# SQL CURDATE Statement

Tags: php, sql

Is it true that the following line will delete every event in the table that happend yesterday ?

```
delete from events where date(event_date) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

if not, how can i delete the events that happend yesterday ?

Comment: CURDATE is probably product specific, which dbms are you using?

Comment: Side note: `date(event_date)` will likely cause the system to do a table scan - not using an index - if that column isn't a date.  If you're clearing out yesterday's rows every day that won't be too much an issue (too large a percentage of rows deleted), although I'd recommend deleting everything older than today in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your query deletes all events older than yesterday. To delete only the events yesterday do

```
delete from events
where date(event_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 1):

For optimization purposes, it is better to use comparisons rather than functions on the column.  If `event_date` has no time component:

```
delete from events
    where event_date = date_sub(CURDATE(), 'INTERVAL 1 DAY');
```

If it does have a time compenent:

```
delete from events
    where event_date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), 'INTERVAL 1 DAY') and
          event_date < CURDATE();
```

In particular, this allows MySQL to use an index for the `WHERE` clause, which can make the query much more efficient.